# Permutations with extra restrictions

Tags: algorithm, math, permutation, combinatorics

I have a set of items, for example: {1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3}, and a restricting set of sets, for example {{3},{1,2},{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{2,3},{2,3}. I am looking for permutations of items, but the first element must be 3, and the second must be 1 or 2, etc.

One such permutation that fits is:
{3,1,1,1,2,2,3}

Is there an algorithm to count all permutations for this problem in general? Is there a name for this type of problem?

For illustration, I know how to solve this problem for certain types of "restricting sets". 
Set of items: {1,1,2,2,3}, Restrictions {{1,2},{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2},{1,2}}. This is equal to 2!/(2-1)!/1! * 4!/2!/2!. Effectively permuting the 3 first, since it is the most restrictive and then permuting the remaining items where there is room.

Also... polynomial time. Is that possible?

UPDATE: This is discussed further at below links. The problem above is called "counting perfect matchings" and each permutation restriction above is represented by a {0,1} on a matrix of slots to occupants.

- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519056/does-a-matrix-represent-a-bijection
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509563/counting-permutations-with-additional-restrictions
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800977/parking-cars-and-vans-into-car-van-and-car-van-parking-spots

Comment: Are you looking only for a count, or are you interested in an algorithm that could also potentially print the permutations? In any case, how efficient must this be?

Comment: Your question looks very interesting to me but I don't fully understand it.

Comment: A count would be fine. Because I can recursively apply the count algorithm to walk or randomly access the n-th permutation if need be.

The algorithm/analytical method would have to be in polynomial time, not the obvious "walk all permutations and strike the ones that don't match the rule" algorithm. Good question.

An equation is just as good as an algorithm for me. References to similar analytical methods or academic publications would also help me.

Comment: Also keywords or formal terms what I am describing would help me research this.

Comment: You might have a better luck at http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a polynomial solution, if there is I'm thinking it's something to do with dynamic programming in `O(n^k)`, where `k` is at most 3, but I don't have anything concrete yet. Not sure if there's a name for this problem either, maybe something like restricted permutations (counting) or simply permutations counting. Maybe you SHOULD also try asking on mathoverflow.net

Comment: I would guess the existence of a permutation is NP-complete. The obvious dynamic programming approach would need to store a count for all subsets, of which there are exponentially many.

Comment: I'm confused about a few things: Sets are usually unordered and have only one of each element, but I suppose you're talking about "ordered multi-sets" or something? Additionally, if there are k restricting sets, does that mean that all permutations must be of length k? What relation is there between the length of the output, the size of the input multiset, and the number of restriction sets?

Comment: FYI, my real problem is counting the number of legal permutations of pieces on a Chinese chess board given which pieces may legally occupy which squares. So this represents a 90x90 matrix. Dynamic programming did NOT work for this project, but I'm working on some tricks that take advantage of self similarity in this particular problem, which is too long to discuss in this stackoverflow comme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the other solutions here are exponential time--even for cases that they don't need to be.  This problem exhibits similar substructure, and so it should be solved with dynamic programming.

What you want to do is write a class that memoizes solutions to subproblems:

```
class Counter {
  struct Problem {
     unordered_multiset<int> s;
     vector<unordered_set<int>> v;
  };

  int Count(Problem const& p) {
    if (m.v.size() == 0)
      return 1;
    if (m.find(p) != m.end())
      return m[p];
    // otherwise, attack the problem choosing either choosing an index 'i' (notes below)
    // or a number 'n'.  This code only illustrates choosing an index 'i'.
    Problem smaller_p = p;
    smaller_p.v.erase(v.begin() + i);
    int retval = 0;
    for (auto it = p.s.begin(); it != p.s.end(); ++it) {
      if (smaller_p.s.find(*it) == smaller_p.s.end())
        continue;
      smaller_p.s.erase(*it);
      retval += Count(smaller_p);
      smaller_p.s.insert(*it);      
    }
    m[p] = retval;
    return retval;
  }

  unordered_map<Problem, int> m;
};
```

The code illustrates choosing an index i, which should be chosen at a place where there are v[i].size() is small.  The other option is to choose a number n, which should be one for which there are few locations v that it can be placed in.  I'd say the minimum of the two deciding factors should win.

Also, you'll have to define a hash function for Problem -- that shouldn't be too hard using boost's hash stuff.

This solution can be improved by replacing the vector with a set<>, and defining a < operator for unordered_set.  This will collapse many more identical subproblems into a single map element, and further reduce mitigate exponential blow-up.

This solution can be further improved by making Problem instances that are the same except that the numbers are rearranged hash to the same value and compare to be the same.

Comment: This is good, I see how a good hash function will greatly affect the complexity of this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Are you certain that this exhibits optimal substructure? You seem to be picking whichever i and n seem good, but I don't see how that reflects some structure of the question.

Comment: It exhibits optimal substructure because knowing the answer to a subproblem helps you build the answer to the larger problem-- in the code above, the recursive Count function first checks if the answer is stored in a map.

Comment: I am still working on this problem. My hardest issue is canonicalizing  the subproblem. My matrix is binary 100x100 with patterns and effectively I am trying to find the permanent.

Comment: @FullDecent: I don't know what you mean…

Comment: I think there's a typo : `if (m.v.size() == 0)` should be `if (p.v.size() == 0)`, isn't ?

Comment: I don't see how this algorithm could solve the problem. Especially, nothing seems to be done with/after the erased set `smaller_p.v.erase(v.begin() + i);`. May be there are some typos in the pseudo code. I expected (just intuition here) that we should erase just one element from `smaller_p.v[v.begin() + i]` at a time from the loop (instead of erasing an element from `smaller_p.s`

Comment: @hamdidouss The numbers are used up by removing them from `v` and `s` and then recursing.  This solution should work if you chose `i` randomly for example.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider a recursive solution that uses a pool of digits (in the example you provide, it would be initialized to  {1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3}), and decides, at the index given as a parameter, which digit to place at this index (using, of course, the restrictions that you supply).

If you like, I can supply pseudo-code.

Comment: that's the right idea, but you want to memoize solutions to the subproblems, or else the solution is exponential for many cases.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a tree.
Level 0: Create a root node.
Level 1: Append each item from the first "restricting set" as children of the root.
Level 2: Append each item from the second restricting set as children of each of the Level 1 nodes.
Level 3: Append each item from the third restricting set as children of each of the Level 2 nodes.
...

The permutation count is then the number of leaf nodes of the final tree.

**Edit**

It's unclear what is meant by the "set of items" {1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3}.  If that is meant to constrain how many times each value can be used ("1" can be used 3 times, "2" twice, etc.) then we need one more step:

- Before appending a node to the tree, remove the values used on the current path from the set of items. If the value you want to append is still available (e.g. you want to append a "1", and "1" has only been used twice so far) then append it to the tree.

Comment: this works, but it is suboptimal when choices you make early-on could have been pruned out, e.g., {1,2,...}, {{1,2,3},.....,{1}}: the single 1 should be put into the final slot, not used early only to discover that we will need it later.

Comment: @Neil - This solution assumes you are allowed to select a value from the set as many times as you want.  It's not clear from the question whether that should be allowed or not.  If it is, then there is no pruning required - all paths are valid.

Comment: if you were allowed to select a number from the set as many times as you want, then why would some numbers be repeated in the set -- why is it a multiset?

Answer (score 0):

To save space, you could build a directed graph instead of a tree.

- Create a root node.
- Create a node for each item in the
  first set, and link from the root to
  the new nodes.
- Create a node for each item in the
  second set, and link from each first
  set item to each second set item.
- ...

The number of permutations is then the number of paths from the root node to the nodes of the final set.